# SQL find if dates fall within a span

Tags: sql, date

Using tsql, I am trying to find if a member has services from each of three separate buckets within a 30 day window. The buckets don't necessarily hold unique values. In my example below member 1 doesn't have all three dates in the window, while member 2 does.

```
create table #dates (
    member tinyint,
    bucket tinyint,
    dt date
);

insert into #dates (member,bucket,dt)
    values (1,1,'20170101'),
           (1,2,'20161225'),
           (1,2,'20170204'),
           (1,3,'20170129'),
           (2,1,'20170101'),
           (2,2,'20170102'),
           (2,3,'20161231');
```

INITIAL QUERY

```
select *
from #dates d1 join
     #dates d2
     on d2.member=d1.member and d2.bucket=2 and
        d2.dt between DATEADD(DAY,-30,d1.dt) and DATEADD(day,30,d1.dt)
where d1.bucket=1
```

Comment: Member 1 has two #2 buckets, is that intentional? Also how do you imagine the output table to appear? One row per member with an indicator field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want members where this is true, then this is one method:

```
select distinct d.member
from #dates d 
where exists (select 1
              from #dates d1
              where d1.member = d.member and d1.bucket = 1 and
                    d1.dt between DATEADD(DAY, -30, d.dt) and DATEADD(day, 30, d.dt)
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from #dates d2
              where d2.member = d.member and d2.bucket = 2 and
                    d2.dt between DATEADD(DAY, -30, d.dt) and DATEADD(day, 30, d.dt)
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from #dates d3
              where d3.member = d.member and d3.bucket = 3 and
                    d3.dt between DATEADD(DAY, -30, d.dt) and DATEADD(day, 30, d.dt)
             ) ;
```